# как получить exif данные фотографии с помощью javaScript?

Tags: javascript, изображения, exif

Загружаю фотографию через `input`, через `input.files[0]` получаю файл в виде объекта `File`, но в свойствах отображаются только имя, размер и дата.
Попытался прочитать через объект `FileReader`, но результат крокозябры.
Может кто подскажет как получить `exif` данные фото до отправки на сервер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно использовать библиотеку exif
в папке examples есть примеры как ее использовать.

https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js